# Crashing on loading gallery adapter for recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Edit: After JonR85's answer it returned the image adapter but now after returning the inflated view it crashes the application

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        var _galleryFragment:View?
          _galleryFragment =   requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.gallery_fragment) as View
              galleryFragment =   GetGalleryFragment(inflater,container) as View


             galleryNumberText =     (galleryFragment).findViewById(R.id.galleryNumber) as? TextView?
             recyclerView = (galleryFragment).findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewImageItems) as? RecyclerView?

             if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context as Context,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.parentFragment?.getActivity() as MainActivity,
                Array<String>(2){Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},READ_PERMISSION_CODE)
            var i:Any?;
        }
        else
        {
            loadImages()
        }
           return galleryFragment
    }
```

I have been trying to setup a recyclerview in a fragment(which first is inflated then assigns the objects(recycler view and the text view) in the class that constains the image with the recyclerview and ask for permision but somehow just when it loads the recyclerview it closes the application(apparently crashes at
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.applicationtest, PID: 14303
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.applicationtest.gallery_fragment.loadImages(gallery_fragment.kt:140)
at com.example.applicationtest.gallery_fragment.onCreateView(gallery_fragment.kt:104)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8037)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

which calls a GalleryAdapter's constructor

abd I have created a galleryElement in a different view to the fragment(I didnt include it), what could be causing the crash?

````
    fun loadImages(){
        recyclerView!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.activity,4)

        try {
            this.imageList = ImageGallery.GetImagesList(this.context as Context )
        }
        catch (ex:Exception)
        {
            println(ex.message)
        }
        galleryAdapter = GalleryAdapter(this.context as Context,imageList,
            object : IPhotoInterface {
                override fun onPhotoClick(stringPath: String):Unit {
                    //process picture on click
                }
            })
       try {
           recyclerView?.adapter = galleryAdapter
           galleryNumberText?.text = "${imageList.size} images"
       }
        catch(ex:Exception)
        {
            println(ex.message)
        }
    }```

GalleryAdapter
````

````
 class GalleryAdapter(var ctx: Context, var listOfImages:MutableList<String>,var photoListener: ViewHolder.IPhotoInterface): RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    
            fun GetImageInit(view:View):ImageView =view.findViewById(R.id.imageElement1)
    
            var image : ImageView
    
            init {
                image  = GetImageInit(itemView) as ImageView
            }
            interface IPhotoInterface {
    
                fun onPhotoClick(stringPath:String): Unit
            }
    
        }
    
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
          var inflatedView:View =  LayoutInflater.from(this.ctx).inflate(R.layout.gallery_fragment,parent,false)
           return ViewHolder(inflatedView)
        }
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            var image:String = (listOfImages as List<String>).get(position)
            Glide.with(ctx).load(image).into(holder.image)
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{view->
                this.photoListener.onPhotoClick(image)
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           return this.listOfImages.size
        }
    }

```

gallery_fragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".gallery_fragment"
    android:background="#333333"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/galleryNumberContainer">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/galleryNumber"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewImageItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
````

````
GalleryItem in a different view file
```xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/gallery_item"
    
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageElement1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            ></ImageView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
````

how I have obtained the image list

```
kotlin
 

public fun GetImagesList(context: Context):MutableList<string>{
            lateinit var uri:Uri
            var cursor:Cursor?
            var columnIndexDataId:Int =0
            var imageCollectionList:MutableList<string> =  mutableListOf<string>()
            var projection:Array<string>
            var absoluteImagePath:String =""
            uri =MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            var selection:string = "_id?"
           // var selectionArgs :Array<string> = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1])

            try {
                val columnName:string="_data"
                projection = arrayOf(columnName)
                cursor =context.contentResolver.query(uri,null,null,null,null)
               //if cursor is not null then execute codeblock
                cursor?.let {
                        while(it.moveToNext())
                        {
                            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnName)
                            absoluteImagePath =cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                            imageCollectionList.add(absoluteImagePath)
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (ex:Exception){
                    print(ex.message)
            }
            return imageCollectionList
        }
```

Comment: What's your full* error message?

Comment: @JonR85 check the OP again I have copied it all

Comment: Thanks for that. What line is 140?

Comment: @JonR85  galleryAdapter = GalleryAdapter(this.context as Context,imageList, as soon it touches the get imageElement it crashes

Comment: @JonR85 apparently it crashes when it tries ot find the element in the fragment view  should I add the image element on the fragment or how does it bind to the fragment view?

Comment: imageList is null, please show the `ImageGallery` code

Comment: @GHH when i checked in the debuged there were 565 files

Comment: Your fragment should only contain your recyclerView(with the exception of elements that are not part of the recyclerView). 
If you don't know how a recyclerview works, I suggest trying to find a tutorial or reading up on them before trying to write one out. They are one of the more complex elements in android.
Just for testing, try removing that interface from the adapter signature.

Comment: @JonR85  https://imgur.com/a/rMEcbbb  it throws an exceptin when obtaining the imageElement off the view... but how it is suposed ot get the image view by id?

Comment: @GHH https://imgur.com/a/rMEcbbb the imageview element wasnt found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var image : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageElement1)

        interface IPhotoInterface {

            fun onPhotoClick(stringPath:String): Unit
        }

    }
```

Comment: aree you suggesing me to not use the constructor?

Comment: thanks now it worked at last ot get the Recycler. but the inflated view in the fragment close the application with the already inflated object... shouldnt I return the inflated view on the onCreatedView method?

Comment: What's your new error message?

Comment: there is none this time but i mean it returns the inflated view(from onViewCreated) and then  crashes(maybe some internal class error an throw no error) maybe has to do how I am invoking the fragment? i am using a navigationview which picks a view and invokes as follow:

Comment: R.id.gallery_fragment ->{
                                  navSideMenu.isVisible=!navSideMenu.isVisible;
                                  val options = NavOptions.Builder()
                                      .setPopUpTo(R.id.gallery_fragment, true)
                                      .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                                      .build()
                                  navigationController.navigate(R.id.gallery_fragment, null, options)
                                  true
                              }

Comment: I keep getting      java.lang.NullPointerException: itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageElement1) must not be null
        at com.example.applicationtest.GalleryAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(GalleryAdapter.kt:20)
        at com.example.applicationtest.GalleryAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.kt:33)
        at com.example.applicationtest.GalleryAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GalleryAdapter.kt:14)

Comment: line 20 var image : ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageElement1)

Comment: To anyone wondering, I was inflating the field for the image´s view rather the id for the ImageView element on the actual layout.. so that was the reason it didnt went through but you were right you should initialze directly not from the ctor